# Do I use the wrong special character? (File not found although it is there)

Tags: command-line, files

I have two files with special characters that I can see on the console with `ls` or `ll` but I can not remove or copy them due to an error `File not found` even if I use the copy and paste option (the last two files):

```
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 ben users 152621799 Nov 16 18:16 2019-08-24-Fahrenunfahrenun.mp3*
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 ben users  99822416 Nov 16 18:16 2019-09-01-Z-Ein Verzedes.mp3*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ben users  95781933 Nov 16 18:13 2019-10-28-Was ist das denn für ein Deräusch?.MP3*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ben users  88689565 Nov 16 18:18 2019-11-09-Wollen wir mal leiser machen?.MP3*
```

Never mind the weird names, it is something my son said. :) Note the difference in the last option `+`. The files that have issues miss the `+`. Trying to copy or remove results in `File or directory not found`.

```
$ rm "2019-10-28-Was ist das denn für ein Deräusch?.MP3"
rm: das Entfernen von '2019-10-28-Was ist das denn für ein Deräusch?.MP3' ist nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

I think it might be related to the special characters `?` and `ä`. Also, the ending is different with capital `.MP3` instead of `.mp3` with the other files that work fine. Any suggestions?

---

EDIT: The output of `ls -li` is:

```
$ ls -li
ls: '2019-10-28-Was ist das denn f¸r ein Der‰usch?.MP3': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
ls: '2019-11-09-Wollen wir mal leiser machen?.MP3': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
insgesamt 3112720
55968313 -rwxr-xr-x+ 1 ben users  48774726 Nov 16 18:18 2019-04-07-1300.mp3
...
55968284 -rwxr-xr-x  1 ben users  95781933 Nov 16 18:13 2019-10-28-Was ist das denn f¸r ein Der‰usch?.MP3
55968312 -rwxr-xr-x  1 ben users  88689565 Nov 16 18:18 2019-11-09-Wollen wir mal leiser machen?.MP3
```

---

Using the **autocomplete** (as suggested in comments) brings up the filename like this but is also not able to actually find the file for removing or copying:

```
$ sudo rm 2019-10-28-Was\ ist\ das\ denn\ für\ ein\ Deräusch\?.MP3
[sudo] Passwort für ben: 
rm: das Entfernen von '2019-10-28-Was ist das denn für ein Deräusch?.MP3' ist nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

---

With `find . -inum 55968284 -delete` (as suggested in comments) I also get `File or directory not found`.

Comment: Try to delete by inode number: `ls -li` and then `find . -inum inode_number -delete`

Comment: The trailing star (`*`) seemingly part of the file name is not actually part of it. The `ll` command appends a `*` on the listing to indicate that the file is *executable*. Please remove the star in the file name in the `rm` command and try again.

Comment: Try entering `rm 2019-10` and pressing TAB for autocompletion of the filename – of course the characters entered have to match one filename exactly for this to work. Another trick is to run `rm -i *`, which asks you whether you want to remove it for every single (non-hidden, by default) file in the directory, one by one.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. For now I just wanted to clarify, that I used the `*` just in one example, because it did not work without the star. I did not think of it beeing part of the filename, however, I wondered what it was. Thanks for telling, although I wonder why a .mp3 is executable...

Comment: Using the autocomplete brings up the filename like this but is also not able to actually find the file for removing or copying: `2019-10-28-Was\ ist\ das\ denn\ für\ ein\ Deräusch\?.MP3`

Comment: With `find . -inum 55968284 -delete` I also get `File or directory not found`.

Comment: Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.

Comment: @dessert yes, of cours, sorry. I put my comments as edits into the question.

Comment: @Ben _“I wonder why a .mp3 is executable...”_ Most likely because it was copied from a filesystem not maintaining UNIX permissions like FAT or NTFS. Regarding the actual problem, I guess the problem comes from Umlauts (which can be encoded in various ways and you can see `ls -li` has a problem with them), not the `?` which could be escaped easily. Please add the full command and output for the autocompleted filename. You could also try a TUI/GUI tool to (re)move the files, like Midnight Commander or Nautilus.

Comment: I updated the question with the exact output from autocomplete. GUI is also not able to remove it, that was actually my first try.

Comment: @Ben Does it work if you try `rm 2019-10*`? (just take care that there isn't any others files which names begin with that, it would remove them too ! Just use the autocompletion - TAB - to take care of it)